# Boost::units::quantity "incomplete type" error

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-units

I am trying to use boost::units in a project but am running into trouble.

I have a template class which has some `quantity` objects as members. In one I wish to store a value with dimensions of pressure so I have `quantity<pressure> press;` declared as a member variable.

However this gives an error saying that `quantity` expects two template arguments (the source code shows the second template argument should default to `double`). If I then specify `quantity<pressure,double> press;` I instead get an error which says

- *error: field ‘press’ has incomplete type.*

Am I doing something wrong or is there a problem with the implementation of pressure somehow?

**Minimal Example:**

```
#include <boost/units/dimension.hpp>
#include <boost/units/systems/si/pressure.hpp>

using namespace boost::units;
using namespace boost::units::si;

struct MyClass
{
    quantity<pressure,double> press;    
};
```

**Details:**

- Boost 1.54.0
- g++ 4.7.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need to include this:

```
#include <boost/units/quantity.hpp>
```

[Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/388725e18b8449ae)

Comment: Thanks, I just figured this out too. Such a rookie error. So is there a `quantity` object in .../dimension.hpp too?

Comment: @Dan Not sure, but I simply looked at the example file they had to see what headers were necessary.